# str_detect, case sensitivity, and mutating a binary variable

Tags: r, string

I am currently working on some research of online forums. I have a database with thousands of posts and want to create a binary variable on the specific post (which is an observation in my dataset) when a certain word is mentioned.

I want to see when posters talk about being lonely, so I have come up with the following code, but I keep getting an error when I use `ignore_case = T`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(string)

dataset <- dataset %>% 
    mutate(loneliness = ifelse(str_detect(text,"loneliness|blackpilled|lonely"), 1, 0, ignore_case = TRUE))
```

I have also tried:

```
mutate(loneliness = ifelse(
  str_detect(dataset$text, regex("loneliness|blackpilled|black pill|lonely", ignore_case = TRUE))))
```

Using that I get this error:  argument "no" is missing, with no default.

What am I missing in my code that it is not working?

Comment: If you check the `str_detect` help page, you'll see it doesn't have an `ignore_case` argument. (That's been gone since 2015 with version 1.0). You can use the base `grepl` which has `ignore.case`, or you can use `stringI::strI_detect()`, which allows you to pass along regex arguments with `opts_regex`, or with `stringr` you can wrap your pattern in `regex()`, which does use `ignore_case`. But `ifelse` requires 3 arguments, `condition`, `yes`, and `no`, and you are calling it with only the condition, you need `, 1, 0`.

Answer (score 1):

you just added `ignore_case` inside the base R `ifelse()`, which is not an argument of that function. Using `dplyr` and `stringr` works perfectly like so:

```r
Data <- data.frame(text = c('I am lonely','I am happy'))
library(tidyverse)
Data |>
  mutate(
    loneliness = if_else(
      condition = str_detect(text, pattern = "loneliness|blackpilled|lonely"),
      1L, 0L
    )
  )
#>          text loneliness
#> 1 I am lonely          1
#> 2  I am happy          0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

On top of `str_detect` not having `ignore_case` natively it's at the wrong position (outside of `str_detect` function but in `ifelse`).

Using `regex` should work though

```
dataset %>% 
  mutate(loneliness = ifelse(
    str_detect(text, 
      regex("loneliness|blackpilled|lonely", ignore_case = T)
    ), 1, 0))
```